# How high is the variance of the shore D hardness for a synthetical resin?

Tags: polymers, materials, mixtures

I realize that the variance of hardness depends on the homogenity of the polymer throughtout a specific sample, the polymer itself and on the measurement, but maybe there are typical values.

To be a bit more specific: Im interested in the order of magnitudes of the variance of hardness an adhesive or resin, mixed exactly as prescribed in the data sheet should have.